# Load webpage with reseting cookies in c# net

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient, webclient

I want to make a simple program, that loads a webpage(eg. to webclieant control) and i want to reset cookies in every time, when i load this page. I don't know, how to do it, so maybe can give me a example how to do it?
Thank you for any help :)

Comment: Can you pst what you have tried? Or what resources you've looked into?

Comment: Thanks for help :)
I'm sorry, but I cannot vote, but I discover, that when i only send a method to get a website, it works really well without reseting cookies, but I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make simple loads using WebClient class of the Framework, it is actually simple. WebClient class can use Cookies by using Headers and ResponseHeaders properties. If you want to clear cookies on every request, just clean the right Header before doing a request. I don't know exactly if this is your question, so I will send an example on how to work with cookies using WebClient. I hope it is what you are looking for.

You can set cookies on WebClient easily by using the Headers property, and get the Cookies that must be sent back using the ResponseCookies property. If you want to manage your cookies, try doing something like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Put your cookies content here
        string myCookies = "Cookie1=Value; Cookie2=Value";

        // The URL you want to send a request
        string url = "https://www.google.com.br/";

        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            // If you want to attach cookies, you can do it 
            // easily using this code.
            client.Headers.Add("Cookie", myCookies);

            // Now you get the content of the response the way 
            // better suits your application.
            // Here i'm using DownloadString, a method that returns
            // the HTML of the response as a System.String.
            // You can use other options, like OpenRead, wich
            // creates a Stream to get the Response content.
            string responseContent = client.DownloadString(url);

            // If you want to save the cookies of the response to
            // use them later, just use the ResponseHeaders property.
            string responseCookies = client.ResponseHeaders["Set-Cookie"];

            // Here is the response of your question (I I'm correct). 
            // If you need to use the same instance of WebClient to make
            // another request, you will need to clear the headers that 
            // are being used as cookies.
            // You can do it easily by using this code.
            client.Headers.Remove("Cookie");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpCookie aCookie;
string cookieName;
int limit = Request.Cookies.Count;
for (int i=0; i<limit; i++)
{
    cookieName = Request.Cookies[i].Name;
    aCookie = new HttpCookie(cookieName);
    aCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
    Response.Cookies.Add(aCookie);
}
```